# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`AB`' given input columns: not able to resolve a variable in spark sql queries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I am using spark SQL APIs in Scala. I am using a variable inside the query.
Below is the code snippet. `DF2_VIEW` is the view created for a dataframe.

```
val x = 'AB'

val newDf = spark.sql(s"""select * from GLOBAL_TEMP.DF2_VIEW
             WHERE $x = SOME_FIELD_IN_DF2_VIEW""")
```

It's showing me the error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot 
resolve '`AB`' given input columns: [COLUMNS NAMES IN DF2_VIEW]
```

I am using Spark 2.2, scala 2.11.8
Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Anyone? I really need help here :(

Comment: I am sorry as I am not allowed to share code... I am just joining two tables. The problem is that spark.sql is not able to parse value of x, it is searching for column name rather than comparing the const value, that is 'AB'

Comment: Please read this - How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have changed the code snippet for you. Basically I ma not able to resolve the const. value inside a spark.sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple working example. Not sure if this is what you require:

```
val df = Seq(("Amy",20),("Tom",18)).toDF("Name","Age")
df.show()

val x = "Amy"

df.createOrReplaceTempView("DF2_VIEW")
val qry = s"""select * from DF2_VIEW where '${x}' = Name"""
spark.sql(qry).show(false)

Output:

+----+---+
|Name|Age|
+----+---+
|Amy |20 |
+----+---+
```

Comment: It worked, Thank you so much. Just one doubt, why is it the case $x was not working with `'WHERE` clause, but working with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`